# Why gcc does not support linking dynamical library into static binary

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries, static-linking

The background is following: there is 3'rd party provider that provides us with a libveryfancylib.so, in 32b. Softaware that uses the library has quite a load of other linux library dependencies (like QT) also, but they are open source, so no problem for statical linking. The target platform is 64b and running Debian 7.

We can ship the program with binary + dynamical libraries, no problem, but i would rather see single static binary with no dependencies.

So my question is: why i cannot link the dynamical library into static binary? I mean what bit of information is there missing, or is it just feature that is rarely needed -> not implemented.

Comment: It is possible though. GCC might not support it because of licensing stuff. Linking agains dynamic and linking against static libraries is two different things, speaking in legal terms. So my guess is, if you were the owner you can make whatever library you want no problem by compiling your sources. But having only dynamic library may mean you are going to do something not very legal. Just a guess...

Comment: Would it be possible to pack the so file with executable and use dlopen or something similiar then to load it dynamically? Just thinking...

Comment: Yeah, doing dlopen wrapper around the library should solve the issue -- and it could be automized for say python script generating wrapper.c, but as the question tries to be, why not do this in the compiler at the first place?

Comment: Can't you just ask the 3rdparty for a static lib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are programs for MS Windows that can do so, eg [DLL to Lib](http://www.binary-soft.com/dll2lib/dll2lib.htm) and [DLL to Static Lib](http://wkdownload.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/dll-to-static-lib.html).

In the open source world, there isn't really much of an incentive to develop such a tool as you can always recompile from source (but of course it's possible that someone somewhere did it anyway).

Comment: To clarify: you say the answer for my question is "gcc is not supporting such, since the feature is not needed"

Comment: @susundberg: correct; it's a non-issue for open source software, commercial vendors might be opposed to someone messing with their binary blobs and the free-software movement wants to discourage use of closed-source software anyway

Answer (score 1):

> We can ship the program with binary + dynamical libraries, no problem, but i would rather see single static binary with no dependencies.

What is the problem you are trying to solve?

You can follow the model most commercial applications on Linux do: put your executable, shared libraries and other resources in one directory (possibly with subdirectories). When linking your executable against those shared libraries pass `-Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN'` (in make use `-Wl,-rpath,'$$ORIGIN'`) to the linker, so that when starting your application the runtime linker looks for required shared libraries in the same directory where executable is.

Then archive that directory and give it to your users.

Comment: You are right of course, and what you suggest is better solution that what we are using right now, but its not answering to the question i tried to ask: "why does not gcc link dynamical libraries into a static executable" -- is it, as suggested, licensing issue, or is it just lack of interest from developers for such feature, or is there even technical 'cant do' (i guess not).

Answer (score 0):

It's because dynamic libraries and static libraries are two different things. A static library is just an archive of object files (much like a zip archive). A dynamic library is more like an executable program.

So you can't really *link* anything into a static library, you can only add more object files.

Comment: Yes they are of different nature, but since the bytecode and the symbolic table is there, what - really! - is preventing me from making the static binary (executable!) from dynamical libraries.

I mean, i can do dlopen wrapper and that should work just fine, right?

Comment: @susundberg A dynamic library is more like an executable file, with data and code sections etc. A static library is an archive, again more like a zip or tar archive. A static library doesn't contain data or code segments, it doesn't have an ELF (on e.g. Linux) header, it doesn't have any rellocation information, and no it doesn't have a list of symbols, just a list of the object files inside the archive.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: if the dynamic linker has enough information to wire everything up, so should a static tool that creates an equivalent object file; just because we cannot recreate the original object files (we probably could do so if enough debug information is available) does not mean we cannot arrive at something that's operationally just as good...